# How can I logout from my tab barviewcontroller application and refresh on iphone apps all tab?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitabbarcontroller, logout

I am beginner iOS Application Developer .I have doing Web-service application and Depend on API .My Application created on tab-bar viewcontrller application .I have used first tab in login detail and fourth tab used in logout button .when iI click logout button I need logout in all tab and refresh login details.Kindly help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not have a login view controller (modal) and then segue to that VC (and clear out any NSUserDefaults or whatever other store you are using to persist user info) when the user "logs out".

My process is:
1.  Clear out NSUserDefaults for the logged in user info
2.  Segue to modal login VC (no tabs visible)
3.  When next user logs in, fire off the delegate (dismisses login VC and saves user info to NSUserDefaults).

Comment: Hi.ElJay.Can you please provide some part of code or reference?

Answer (score 0):

You can register the view controllers for a logout notification. When your viewcontroller on first tab posts the logout notification, the needed code can be performed by other viewcontrollers.

How to create and observe your own notifications? Please refer here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Notifications/Introduction/introNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000043i

Answer (score 0):

Just put logout button in navigation bar of all view and on click of it remove the value you have stored as login id and password and just do this[As you have login screen in first view]

```
[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];
```